# foreach use them multiple times

Tags: php

```
http://pastebin.com/MFCQzJQ8
```

I have this code and I am trying to get it to output the result

```
echo $attack.' Attacks Have Been Stopped On Server '.$id.'<br>';
```

different every time but I can only get the server id or the attack to change but I need both to change and output on a new line ever time.

http://gyazo.com/f38c20ecef5af72dcc534be88101f8a2

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['stop']))
    {
        $ids = $_POST['id'];
        $urls = $_POST['url'];
        $attacks = $_POST['attack'];
        foreach($urls as $url);
        foreach($attacks as $attack);
        foreach($ids as $id);


            echo '<div class="nNote nSuccess hideit"><p><strong>SUCCESS: </strong><br>';

            foreach($ids as $id){
            if($attack == "NONE"){$attack = "No";}
            echo $attack.' Attacks Have Been Stopped On Server '.$id.'<br>';
            }
            echo '</p></div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Post your code here, not a link to pastebin.

Comment: Could you give more info. What's actually happening instead,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the arrays into one and iterate over it:

```
foreach(array_map(null,$ids,$urls,$attacks) as list($id,$url,$attack)) {
    // code body here
}
```

Comment: I've just realised how sexy that code is. I know several places I can use it that previously had assorted hacks/loops instead.